# Scanner only recognizes certain lines in a text file but not others

Tags: java, text-files, java.util.scanner

I have a txt file of names and genders that I imported for this java program. The scanners are supposed take a user input (name and gender) and compare it line by line to find it within the text file and then print the line at which the name was found. However, only some names work and not others. I think it may be because the program only reads every other line but im not sure if thats the problem, or how to fix it. 
Link to the name file: http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse142/16au/homework/names.txt

```
public static void fileSearch() throws FileNotFoundException {
    System.out.println("What name are you looking for?");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name = scan.nextLine();
    String gender = scan.nextLine();
    File file = new File("names.txt");
    Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(file);
    while (fileScan.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = fileScan.nextLine();
        Scanner lineScan = new Scanner(line);
        String nameText = lineScan.next();
        String genderText = lineScan.next();
        if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(nameText) && gender.equalsIgnoreCase(genderText)) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Is it always the same names that are not correctly handled? And could you provide an example of a name, that is not working?

Comment: The `names.txt` seems to have its information in columns and not lines? Have you tried to debug the output to see what values you get for `name`, `gender`, `nameText`, `genderText`?

Comment: It seems that your program is working fine.I chose random names form your file and test them.it worked as expected.
In which names you are having problem? can you put any of these cases.